# HTML editor for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml

I am looking for a html editor for windows phone 8.1 store apps(like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) for web).
I want users to be able to create rich text e.g with bold,underlining,italics among other styles from a windows phone 8.1 app.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Html pro ? look here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/html-pro/9wzdncrdxjn9

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need a tool that I can use within my app